# What does gray text when adding dependency mean in m2e?

Tags: m2eclipse, m2e

When I add dependencies in Dependency Management section of pom.xml, sometimes m2e shows them in gray. Does anybody know what this means? I can see this happens when the dependencies are related to ones already added.

[image]

Is it just that they are modules of an already added multi-module pom, and is this an indication that adding them isn't necessary?

Answer (score 3):

I digged into the source code of the m2e plugin and found one possible match and a possible explanation:

```
    if(scope != null && !"compile".equals(scope)) { //$NON-NLS-1$
      return Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GRAY);
    }
```

From [DependencyTreePage](http://git.eclipse.org/c/m2e/m2e-core.git/tree/org.eclipse.m2e.editor/src/org/eclipse/m2e/editor/pom/DependencyTreePage.java#n764)

If the dependency's scope is not empty and not *compile* it is displayed in grey. This may be the case, if you are adding test dependencies or provided libraries (like jsp-api etc.)